# Swagger how to set template class as API endpoint return type

Tags: java, api, generics, swagger, resteasy

I'm using swagger to document my API and one of my endpoints is returning a generic type `QueryResult<MyType>`:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/query")
  @ApiOperation(response = QueryResult.class)
  public QueryResult<MyType> queryHttpGet() {     
      return new QuertyResult<MyType>();
  }
```

However, I cannot set `response=QueryResult<MyClass>.class` in `@ApiOperation`, so I won't know the actual type in my API definition file that is generated.

There are several discussions:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/498

https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/416

ans some mention to implement a small shim class:

```
 public class MyTypeQueryResult extends QueryResult<MyType> {       
 }
```

and then pass `response=MyTypeQueryResult` to `@ApiOperation`
but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas how I can see the generic type in my swagger definition?

Comment: AFAIK Java's generics are erased at compile time, hence there is no way to achieve what you want. Using a subclass works most of the time, but you should provide a MWE and the error traceback.